# Bound on function

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose a set $|I_{r}| \leq O(r^{2})$ but also $|I_{r}| \geq \rho^{r}$ where $\rho=(1+\epsilon).$ Why is it true that there must always be an $r^{*}=f(\rho)$ such that the condition is true for all values $r=0,1,2,...r^{*}-1$, but not for any $r \geq r^{*}$.

I'm sure logic dictates that there must be an $r^{*}$ for which $\rho^{r}> O(r^{2})$ but is this always the case? For example if $\epsilon=0.01$ and $O(r^{2})=r^{2}$

Then graphically it seems $1.01^{r}<r^{2}$ Unless I'm incorrect in this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is that, for some constant $M$, $(1+\epsilon)^r \le M r^2$. This may never be true, depending on the value of $M$. However, it requires (by taking logarithms) that $$r \log(1+\epsilon) \le \log M + 2 \log r,$$ which in turn implies (for $r \ge e$) that
$$ \frac{r}{\log r} \le \frac{\log M + 2 \log r}{\log r} \le \log M + 2.$$ 
Since $r/\log r \to \infty$ as $r \to \infty$, there must be a largest (if any) integer $r$ for which the inequality holds.

Comment: So then surly the same holds for any constant $M$?

Comment: $\frac{r}{\mathrm{log} r} \leq \frac{2}{\mathrm{log}(1+\epsilon)}+\frac{\mathrm{log} M}{log r}$

Comment: Ok thanks, so why have you said this may never be true depending on the value of $M$? Surely for any constant $M$ there will exist an $r$ for which $r/\mathrm{log}(r)>log(M)+2$ as it's an increasing function?

Comment: Your restriction is that $r$ is a nonnegative integer. If (say) $\epsilon = 1$ and $M = .00001$ it will never be true.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks!